# python return particular substring if its present in the string with case insensitive

Tags: string, return, substring, match, contains

I am currently trying to return a substring if is present in a string, with case insensitive.

So an example would be, I want to return the string "apple" even when the sentence is "Apple is cool" or "I like APPLE" or "I like apples"

What I have so far is this:

```
words = [x for x in df_word_list['word'].tolist() if x in str(df['sentence'][i])]
```

this gives me the returned words, but its case sensitive, anyone knows how to turn it into case insensitive?

df_words_list is the dataframe of words that I want to identify. df is the dataframe that contains the sentences.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please add the language as a tag next time. Easier to find that way.

If you want it to be non case-sensitive cast both word to lower eg.:

```
words = [x for x in df_word_list['word'].tolist() if x.lower() in str(df['sentence'][i]).lower()]
```

Note that it is faster if you store the sentences in lower case from the begining. because that way you only have to cast once to lowercase.